# what is the meaning of this sentences please tell me

Tags: sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of this sentences, please tell me--""That she should forget me so quickly was rather a shock.""

Comment: It’s just inverted: “It was rather a shock that she should forget me so quickly”

Answer (score 1):

The sentence simply means that *The person is shocked because he did not expect the woman to forget him so quickly*.

Comment: why there "should " used

Comment: i think ... "should" not to be used there

Comment: Maybe he was expecting her to forget him (hence the should) but not so quickly

Comment: @KapilSaini There is nothing wrong with the use of *should* and the infinitive. It's being used as a subjunctive.